# How to import a barrel by folder name only?

Tags: javascript, angular

## Angular 2 Barrels

**In Angular 2, I'm trying to get barrels to work as described in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B).**

The official [Angular 2 style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#create-and-import-barrels) talks about using **barrels** to aggregate and shorten `import` statements.

I'm finding out that for some barrels, I have to specify the `index` JavaScript file name on the import when I shouldn't have to.

#### Barrel Example

*(modify the app/app.component.ts file on line 12)*

After have encountered this in my actual project (running under ASP.NET) I have created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tfP9OE?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem where I modified the Tour of Heroes to use barrels.

In `app/app.component`, the basic way to import is like this:

```
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
```

But, to use a barrel instead, the import definition would look like this:

```
import {
  HeroService,
  HeroesComponent,
  HeroDetailComponent
} from '../app';
```

The `from '../app';` line indicates a file with the name of `index.ts` that contain the exported/imported components:

```
// app/index.ts
export * from './hero-detail.component';
export * from './hero.service';
export * from './heroes.component';
```

But this doesn't work for me in all cases. The only way I've gotten this to work correctly is by explicitly including the `index` file name:

```
import {
  HeroService,
  HeroesComponent,
  HeroDetailComponent
} from '../app/index'; // have to indicate 'index'
```

**How can I get this to work where the `index.js` file name is implied?**

Comment: Looks like a bug or maybe the docs are wrong. Would be nice to import it only with the folder name as in ES6

Comment: My understanding is that NodeJS will look for an *index.js* file if you only reference a directory for the "require" or in this case "import" call.  I am not sure if Plunkr can mimick this behavior.

Comment: @Mdd, that's a good point about Plunker. Although, I'm using ASP.NET in my actual project where I first encountered this problem, so it is failing in a real environment.

Comment: AFAIK, `app` can't work as a `barrelName` because you've already specified the default for it `{ main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' }`, and that's what it's all about to configure a barrel, see my answer for that

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK `SystemJS` doesn't understand barrels by itself but `Webpack` does.
BTW, After digging up how `Angular` does it for it's modules, I've found a solution

---

In [**`system.config.js`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#config-files) you'll need to do the following things

**Note:** the parent directory of a **`index.ts`** is the **`barrel`**, ICYDK

- **Add the paths of your barrels**

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',

    'barrel':                 'path/to/your/barrel'
  };
```

- **Don't add barrels to `packages`** *(explained later)<sup>##</sup>*

```
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'app/boot.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
```

- **Add them to `packageNames`, just like angular**

```
var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    ...
    '@angular/upgrade',

    'barrel'
  ];
```

And you're done.

---

**##**

Why we used `packageNames` instead of `packages` is because you'll have to repeat the `{ main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }` (filename and extension) for every `barrel`, but angular is already doing it by looping with this.

```
packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});
```

Which is ultimately adding them to `packages`.

---

**Usage**

```
import {something} from '../../barrel'; // relative path to directory of barrel
```

and

```
import {something} from 'barrel'; // name of barrel
```

Both work, but the later one fails to provide `intellisense` and shows an error saying `cannot find module 'barrel'`. Which I don't have a solution for. But I'll add it when I do.

Comment: Wouldn't the new [typescript 2 module resolution enhancements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#module-resolution-enhancements-baseurl-path-mapping-rootdirs-and-tracing) help with the `import {something} from 'barrel'` problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is all seems overly complicated.

There's no need to add anything to map, since `app`, which should be containing everything is already in there. We can just create an array with the subpackages. In my case that was:

```
var subPackageNames = [
        '+heroes',
        '+heroes/shared',
        '+heroes/hero-list',
        '+heroes/hero-detail',
        '+heroes/hero-dashboard'
    ];
```

and then modify the provided `packIndex` function to take a second argument

```
function packIndex(pkgName, baseName) {
    packages[baseName+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
```

now we can add our sub packages to the packages object just like angular does.

```
ngPackageNames.forEach(name => setPackageConfig(name, '@angular/'));
subPackageNames.forEach(name => packIndex(name, 'app/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed *A_Singh's* idea, but had to adapt it a little since my `systemjs.config.js` is different, based on the [tour-of-heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial as of right now. (June 3, 2016 - RC1).

This modification works, and under VisualStudio Code, `Intellisense` worked well for me.

I have also, been playing with directory structure to keep things modular, and here is where the barrels made sense.

This is how I have modified the `tour-of-heroes` project

```
app
|- main.ts
|- app.component.ts
|- app.component.css
|-+ components
| |-+ dashboard
|   |- dashboard.component.css
|   |- dashboard.component.html
|   |- dashboard.component.ts
|-+ modules
| |-+ hero
|   |- index.ts   <-- //The barrel for the Hero module
|   |-+ components 
|   | |-+ detail
|   | | |- hero-detail.component.css
|   | | |- hero-detail.component.html
|   | | |- hero-detail.component.ts
|   | |-+ list
|   |   |- hero-list.component.css
|   |   |- hero-list.component.html
|   |   |- hero-list.component.ts
|   |-+ models
|   | |- hero.model.ts
|   |-+ services
|     |- hero.service.ts
|     |- mock-heroes.ts
```

And here the updated `systemjs.config.js`

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',

    // The added barrel map
    'hero':                       'app/modules/hero'
  };
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },

    // The package definition (notice I had to declare index.js)
    'hero':                       { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And finally, here is how the `app.component.ts` now looks like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroListComponent, HeroDetailComponent, HeroService } from './modules/hero';

@Component({
    selector:   'my-app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:  [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HeroService
    ],
    template:   `
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['HeroList']">Hero List</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css']
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/hero-list',
        name: 'HeroList',
        component: HeroListComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/detail/:id',
        name: 'HeroDetail',
        component: HeroDetailComponent
    }
])
export class AppComponent {
    title: string = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

One final note, you could do the import as

```
import { HeroListComponent, HeroDetailComponent, HeroService } from 'hero';
```

And it will work, however, since it is not technically a NodeJS imported module, VS Code complains that it cannot find it.
So, my personal choice is to leave the explicit `./modules/hero`, it helps me know that it is one of my modules and not an imported one and I'm happy to not see red lines.

Comment: Strange, can't make it work, tried in many different ways. Getting "Error: Typescript found the following errors: ***.ts (13, 34): Cannot find module 'hero'."

Comment: I just wanted to quickly reply to you, let me get read of my compiled files and I'll upload my project to my GIT repo so you can take a look at it. (I'll let you know when I'm done uploading it)

Comment: Hey Vladimir, sorry for the delay, I got busy and just got a chance to upload my sources. https://github.com/alphazygma/angular2-tour-of-heroes-barrel

Comment: np. After Angular RC5 there's almost no need for barrels.

Comment: Awesome, I'll definitely will take a look now, looking forward to it, thanks Vladimir

Comment: Barrels are dead with NG2!

Comment: @VladimirTolstikov can you elaborate?  The style guide seems to differ

Comment: @Brett, sorry, not found an answer and not searching for it anymore, for now.