# How can I get my Angular 2 app to work with barrel file imports?

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to follow the Angular 2 style guideline 04-10 Create and Import Barrels found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html

When I run my app, angular now tries to load a file that doesn't exist: "my-component-name-here.js".

To illustrate the problem, I've modified the Angular 2 sample app to use a barrel file and it throws a 404 error now as well.

I put the heroes component files into their own folder called heroes. I created a new file called heroes/index.ts:

```
export * from './heroes/heroes.component';
```

I changed the import statement in app.component.ts to:

```
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes';
```

When the app tries to load it has the following error as seen in the developer console:

```
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/heroes.ts(…)
```

The plunkr is found here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YXY0PwuFot1g1s6qTqDt?p=preview

I suspect this has something to do with SystemJS but I don't know enough about it to fix it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082601/how-to-import-a-barrel-by-folder-name-only

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer below if it sufficiently addressed your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to make few changes to make barrel work,

**index.ts**

```
   export * from './heroes.component';
```

**systemjs.config.js**

Add an entry to `map` like below,

```
  'heroes':                     'app/heroes',
```

then in `packages` make an entry like below,

```
  'heroes': { main: 'index.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
```

This will resolve `barrel` issue, but does not completely resolve all your issue as you have reference to `hero-detail` as well inside heroes component, so you have to work on those.

Comment: I tried adding your changes to the plunkr but am getting this error now:
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading /app/heroes/heroes/heroes.component.ts(…)

Comment: i still see export * from './heroes/heroes.component'; in your app/heroes/index.ts, it should be export * from './heroes.component';

Answer (score 0):

As a far I can see in your plunkr, the `HeroesComponent` class is located within the `app/heroes/heroes.component.ts` file. So I would use the following instead:

```
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
```