# Typescript - simplify imports

Tags: import, module, typescript, angular

Is there way to import modules with alias?
E.g. I have angular service in folder `common/services/logger/logger.ts`.
How to make import looks like `import {Logger} from "services"` where "services" contains all my services?

I've looked at [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/namespaces.html) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md) but didn't understand how I can use it.

Comment: You want to import a class called `Logger` from a file called `services`?

Comment: I want agregate all my classes in one file and make it accessable by "services" name. Because I don't really want to write always full path to each module when I want to import it.

Comment: The same as `import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";`. So "@angular/core" is a kind of alias. Is there way to do it?

Comment: it's called a [barrel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html). [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082601/how-to-import-a-barrel-by-folder-name-only/37207293#37207293) might do what you want

Comment: Thanks! It solves the problem. It is time to inject webpack in ionic 2 app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I used webpack. If you want to import dependencies everywhere you want, you will need to add alias in webpack config. For example, you have folder `shared` in root with `services` folders in it. Folder `services` should have `index.ts` that exports all services you need (e.g `Logger`). So alias would be `"services" => "shared/services"`.

To make autocomplete work in WebStorm you just need to mark `shared` folder as a "Resource root".

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem. How does `services` or anyone else know that he wants to import `Logger`, and how does he get `Logger` from `ServiceName`?

Comment: It is just shorter path to folder that available everywhere. Do you mean that I need to describe how to configurate webpack and what structure of folders should be?

Comment: I have updated my answer, is it clear now? `ServiceName` is actually `Logger` itself that should be exported in `index.ts` in `services` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Create one file that contains all of your services and give it a name, e.g. `services.ts`. That file can be seen as a barrels, because it will contain and export all of your services. The file could look like this:

```
export * from './logger/logger';
export * from ...;
etc.
```

Now you can import this single file as follow:

```
import * as Services from 'common/services';
```

Then you can access your servies via `Services.Logger`, or directly import the service you want via:

```
import {Logger} from 'common/services';
```

Note, you have change the paths since this is just an example. For more information about this technique, have a look [here](http://tattoocoder.com/angular2-barrels/?utm_content=bufferfd8d0&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer).

Comment: I'm a lazy person :) It is the same thing. Is there a way to make alias that is accessable over all application? In order to not to write `import {Logger} from "../../../../services"`?

Comment: You mean globally accessable in all files?

Comment: You always have to import it. My proposed technique however makes it easier because you can import a single file and then use your services.

Comment: Yeah, globally. So why typescript has modules and namespaces? Is there no another way?

Comment: No, and thats how it works. Importing isn't bad and making all your services globally accessable doesn't sound right to me. Import your services where you need them.

Comment: As @A_Singh wrote we can use webpack to help us with it.

Comment: I know, its exactly what I wrote in my answer except the integration with Webpack.

Comment: But without webpack integration relative paths are still existing.