# Angular2 - Importing 3rd party javascript in SystemJS

Tags: javascript, express, angular, gulp

fileSaver not getting mapped for some reason.  angular2-jwt is working fine.

I did `npm install file-saver -save` to get file-saver then referenced it as follows (I have a gulp task to move the js file to libs directory and I see the file there)

in index.htmlI have included the script in src and system.config

```
    <script src="libs/file-saver/FileSaver.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          } 
        } ,
        map: {
          "angular2-jwt": "libs/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js"
          ,"fileSaver":"libs/file-saver/FileSaver.js"
        }
      });
      System.import('app/bootstrap')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

component.ts

here it is not finding the fileSaver

```
import {SaveAs} from 'fileSaver';
```

the error I get is this

```
 error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fileSaver'.
```

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Comment: Are you developing with TypeScript or JS?

Comment: I am using Typescript

Comment: I am literally pulling my hair out on this one ..

Comment: see this [related Quetion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082601/how-to-import-a-barrel-by-folder-name-only).

Comment: Why would angular2-jwt work and not the other one ? This is strange.. Is it looking for some additional file in file-saver which it cannot find ?

Comment: Did you resolve this?? I am using FileSaver but I'm using it with Webpack, not SystemJS, sorry

Comment: Not the way I wanted it to .. but by doing this I could use  saveAs `declare var saveAs: any;` in the component.

Comment: Did you install the typings?

Comment: yes, I have that installed.

Comment: Hey @Spock How did you insert FileSaver.js using webpack ?

Comment: @TechnoCracker Just outside my my component definition I just import it: "let fileSaver = require('filesaver.js');"

Answer (score 2):

In my case I made it work like this:

**package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    // ... all angular dependencies
    "file-saver": "1.3.2"
 },
```

**index.html**:

```
<!-- all angular dependencies and other 3rd party -->
<script src="node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

**typings.json**:

```
// other typings needed
"filesaver": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/FileSaver/FileSaver.d.ts#d21f1bd1fd079bbc18bc88ed71d2be7f5707e33a"
```

**usage**:

```
var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/zip'});
saveAs(blob, 'project.zip');
```

You need to perform a `npm install` before running it.

That's it, hope it helps.

> This won't let you `import {SaveAs} from 'fileSaver';` nor have full code completion, but at
>   least it works

Comment: I found this helpful as well: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation

Answer (score 0):

In installed the library and the typings (@types).  Then,

```
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';
```

worked. 
Additionally, I had to set the module format of file-saver to cjs explicitely in the System JS configuration:

```
"packages":{
     "file-saver":{
          "main":"FileSaver.js", 
          "format": "cjs"
     }
}
```

As far as I understand SystemJS will recognize file-saver as AMD module by default. Maybe there is something wrong with the AMD module definition in file-saver, but I have not a very deep understanding of this. (See also https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js#L182)

Without setting cjs module format, I got "fileSaver.saveAs is not a function" at runtime.