# index.d.ts vs. normal type file?

Tags: typescript

If I want one place to define my types accessible to the rest of the project, am I supposed to use `index.d.ts` or just define like any other `.ts` file?

Currently, I have a folder `<root>/src/types/index.ts` that works, and it compiles to `<root>/dist`, where `<root>` contains `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, etc. I was wondering if this was normal practice or if I am supposed to define a `index.d.ts`. I am unsure of the usage of `index.d.ts` because it seems like it is for when publishing `.js` npm modules, whereas I just have my own small project that is all `.ts`. Also if I am to use `index.d.ts`, should it go at the level of `<root>` or `<root>/src`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> If I want one place to define my types accessible to the rest of the project, am I supposed to use `index.d.ts` or just define like any other `.ts` file?

**TL;DR:** If you are have an **existing** JavaScript library, you use a  `.d.ts` file to define its types. If you are creating **new** types in your project from scratch, you use `.ts` files.

`.d.ts` files are type definition files. Their purpose is to allow interacting with third party JavaScript APIs in a strongly typed manner via TypeScript.
You can learn more about these files on [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) and search for existing definitions using [Microsoft's TypeSearch](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).
If you are using an API that you cannot find type definitions for, you might consider writing your own `.d.ts` files following [Microsoft's guidelines](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). You might also take a look at [how to produce a .d.ts “typings” definition file from an existing JavaScript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript).

> I want one place to define my types **accessible to the rest of the project**

You might want to checkout [barrels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082601/how-to-import-a-barrel-by-folder-name-only).
Barrels are a way to aggregate multiple modules so you can import their content with a single statement. See also: [What are all the index.ts used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564906/what-are-all-the-index-ts-used-for)
This allows you more flexibility when structuring your project as you can have multiple files in multiple folders and aggregate them for easier importing.
Note that you would need a module bundler such as webpack that supports using barrels.

> Also if I am to use `index.d.ts`, should it go at the level of `<root>` or `<root>/src`?

This is not exactly a matter of it being `index.d.ts` or `index.ts` but of [module resolution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).